# ElasticSearch search pdf document for content

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-lex

I'm working on a project leveraging `AWS Lex chatbot` and `ElasticSearch`. My goal is to parse a query with the intent of searching a single pdf document and pulling out some relevant information.

I'm under the impression this is possible with `ElasticSearch`, though my research has reached a roadblock. I understand `ElasticSearch` has the ability to index documents, but that seems to be limited to indexing actual files for the search of files that match the query. I'm hoping to snag actual content within the PDF document and attempt to pull some content out based on a query. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Elasticsearch can't index PDFs directly. You can extract the text of the PDF, index it, then query as usual. [Apache Tika](https://tika.apache.org/) "detects and extracts metadata and text from over a thousand different file types (such as PPT, XLS, and PDF)."

You can run Tika as a Docker container: [docker-tikaserver](https://github.com/LogicalSpark/docker-tikaserver)

To index a PDF, send your data to Tika (for this example, running as a docker container accessible via http://tika:9998), get the text, and index it:

```
doc = {...} # other content to index
try:
    # open PDF and read contents into data
    # send content to tika to extract text
    doc["content"] = requests.put("http://tika:9998/tika", data=data).text
    es.index(index="my-index", id=doc["id"], body=doc))
except Exception as e:
    log.error("error extracting text: %s", e)
```